# Java Bulk Insert with Shared Entity Manager

Tags: java, database, hibernate, session, bulkinsert

I am trying to write a method that bulk adds entities to the database. Here's my method:

```
@Transactional
protected void bulkInsert(List<?> entities) {
    int batchSize = 25;
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        entities.parallelStream().forEach(e -> {
            em.persist(e);
            if ( i.get() > 0 && i.get() % batchSize == 0 ) {
                em.flush();
                em.clear();
            }
            i.incrementAndGet();
        });
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        LOG.error("Error", e);
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:248) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.getTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

I tried removing the `@Transactional` annotation and still the same error. I tried using Session by doing `Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);` but that still resulted in an error (although different error)

How do I bulk insert objects?

Comment: Did you try removing `em.getTransaction().begin();`/`em.getTransaction().commit();` and leaving `@Transactional`?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Ok I tried that and it gave me an error: `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)`

Comment: Include `@Transactional` and please check under which package u added. It should be `org.springframework.....` .Sometimes when unknowingly added `javax.persistence.transactional...` this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in pure hibernate exists managed- and non-managed environments

> Non-managed environment
>
> If an JPA persistence layer runs in a non-managed environment, database >connections are usually handled by Hibernate's pooling mechanism behind the >scenes. The common entity manager and transaction handling idiom looks like > this:
>
> // Non-managed environment idiom
>
> EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); EntityTransaction tx =
>   null; try {
>        tx = em.getTransaction();
>        tx.begin();
>
> ```
>  // do some work
>  ...
>
>  tx.commit(); } catch (RuntimeException e) {
>  if ( tx != null && tx.isActive() ) tx.rollback();
>  throw e; // or display error message } finally {
>  em.close(); }
> ```
>
> Using JTA 
>   If you use bean-managed transactions (BMT), the code will
>   look like this:
>
> // BMT idiom 
>   @Resource public UserTransaction utx; 
>   @Resource public
>   EntityManagerFactory factory;
>
> public void doBusiness() {
>       EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
>       try {
>
> ```
> // do some work
> ...
>
> utx.commit(); } catch (RuntimeException e) {
> if (utx != null) utx.rollback();
> throw e; // or display error message 
> } finally {
> em.close();
> ```
>
> }
>
> With Container Managed Transactions (CMT) in an EJB3 container, transaction >demarcation is done in session bean annotations
>   or deployment descriptors, not programatically. The EntityManager will
>   automatically be flushed on transaction completion (and if you have
>   injected or lookup the EntityManager, it will be also closed
>   automatically). If an exception occurs during the EntityManager use,
>   transaction rollback occurs automatically if you don't catch the
>   exception. Since EntityManager exceptions are RuntimeExceptions they
>   will rollback the transaction as per the EJB specification (system
>   exception vs. application exception).

you should follow on of two princeple.

annotation @Transactional it's spring annotaniot not hibernate. if you didn;t configued it (or you did configured spring) doen't work.

PC

> An EntityManager is an inexpensive, non-threadsafe object that should
>   be used once, for a single business process

call  em.flush() ,em.clear() might be dangerous  .